# terminator requires java 6 or newer?

Tags: 12.04, terminator

I installed terminator (org.jessies.terminator.i386.deb) on ubuntu 12.04 but after executing it i got this error.
"Terminator requires Java 6 or newer.

http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ may link to a suitable JRE, if you can't use one provided by your OS vendor"

can anyone help me on this?
Farooq

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the terminal emulator [`terminator`](http://gnometerminator.blogspot.fr/p/introduction.html), it does not need Java and it is installable from the main repositories. This is what you get when installing on a fresh 13.04 install:

```
terdon@oregano ~ $ sudo apt-get install terminator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

The following extra packages will be installed:
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0 libkeybinder0 liborbit2
  libvte-common libvte9 python-gnome2 python-keybinder python-pyorbit
  python-vte
Suggested packages:
  libbonobo2-bin desktop-base libgnomevfs2-bin libgnomevfs2-extra gamin fam
  gnome-mime-data python-gnome2-doc python-pyorbit-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common
  libglade2-0 libgnome2-0 libgnome2-bin libgnome2-common libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common libgnomevfs2-0
  libgnomevfs2-common libidl-common libidl0 libkeybinder0 liborbit2
  libvte-common libvte9 python-gnome2 python-keybinder python-pyorbit
  python-vte terminator
```

As you can see in the output above, there is no java or JRE requirement and you can install terminator (which is a python program) directly from the Ubuntu repositories.

---

There are actually two terminal emulators with the same name. The one you tried to install does indeed need Java and if you are really sure you want that one, despite its being much heavier (java) and complicated to install, you can install a JRE with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

I stress however, that installing jre to get a terminal emulator is ridiculous. As far as I can tell both terminator flavors have the same functionality but the one you want to install is simply much much much heavier on the system. Still, your choice.

Comment: I want to install (org.jessies.terminator.i386.deb)

Comment: @Farooq I know, I was suggesting that you install the other one which is just as good and does not need java. Anyway, see updated answer for how to install the jre.

Comment: @Farooq I just gave you the right answer. My update explains how to install JRE and that is what your terminator is complaining about.

Comment: @Farooq sorry, my last comment was not meant to be aggressive. I mean that if you want to install org.jessies.terminator.i386.deb, you will need to first install `openjdk-7-jre` as I explain in my answer and _then_ install the terminator deb again. That is what the error message you received was complaining about: not having a Java Runtime ENgine (JRE).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Oracle version over OpenJDK. Java 7 should work. Installation is described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Comment: Axel i tried this but got this error. "root@farooq:/home/administrator# apt-geckages have unmet dependencies:
 oracle-java7-installer : Depends: java-common (>= 0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                          Recommends: gsfonts-x11 but it is not going to be installed
 python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).